# Bind Links To GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I render links in columns of WebForms GridView?

I have the following code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.UsersContacts WHERE UserId='vika'", con);

con.Open();

var list1 = new List<string>();
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var node = reader[1];
        list1.Add(node.ToString());
    }
}
con.Close();

GridView1.DataSource = list1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and I want to do something such as `list1.Add("<a href='#'>"+node.ToString()+"<a>");` and make it a link in my GridView.

Comment: Why do you want to do this at the code behind instead of directly adding the 'HyperLinkField' or 'HyperLink' at the gridview template definition and binding the 'node' value?

Comment: Also, FYI, you should have your `SqlCommand` in a `using` block as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather do this at the gridview template definition instead of passing the link from the datasource. Your gridview definition can have the `asp:HyperLinkField` or `asp:HyperLink` field and bind the data as required.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">  
     <Columns>  
            <asp:HyperLinkField   
                HeaderText="View Details"  
                DataNavigateUrlFields="node"  
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/TargetPage.aspx?Id={0}"  
                DataTextField="node"  
                />  
     </Columns>  
</asp:GridView>
```

Or

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("node", "~/TargetPage.aspx?Id={0}") %>' Text="View Details" />
```