# Showing url in BoundField in gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am developing a chatting web application with the help of the gridview....The problem is when the user enter the link and it is saved in the database and when the data is retrieved in the gridview the link should be click able. The field I am using to retrieve the data is BoundField.

I don't want to use hyperlink field because then in every row there will a link. I only want to display link when a user will enter a link.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" CssClass="amit1"  >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="m1" HeaderText="Message" SortExpression="m1" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Larger" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="280px" />
                    <ItemStyle Font-Size="Medium" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="280px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>


                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
                DataFile="~/App_Data/gold.accdb" 


                SelectCommand="SELECT [m1] FROM [Chat_detail] WHERE ([Chat_id] = ?)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Chat_id" QueryStringField="chat_id" 
                        Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Is there is any way to do this???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add Hyperlink, make use of RowDataBound event to make that hyperlink visible tru/false based on the value.

See Below:

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
     {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
        HyperLink hlnk = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hlnkUserEnetredLink");
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hlnk))
           {
             hlnk.Visible = true;
            }
      else
           {
             hlnk.Visible = false;
           }
       }
     }

Add that Hyperlink in your aspx page -- in Gridview..

Comment: can u please share the code snippet...thank you. If you are talking about hyperlink filed then i don't want to use it because then all the data will have link.

Comment: see the code, in row data bound event you can make that link visible true or false based on the value.

Comment: thanks for your effort, can u explain what is "hlnkUserEnetredLink" and also there is an error in hlnk that "Value of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink' cannot be converted to 'String'."

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the hyperlink in your code behind based on whatever condition. Note: Making `visible = true/false` will leave a empty cell in the gridview column.

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
     // find the HyperLink defined in the fridview definition
     HyperLink myHyperLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hpLinkUrl");

     //userstoredlink is the datasource field that holds the user stored link       
     string userLink =  DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "userstoredlink").ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userLink))
        { 
            // disable link
            myHyperLink.Enabled = false;
        }
  }
}
```

Please refer [my another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291922/bind-links-to-gridview/24293501#24293501) on different ways to add hyperlink to gridview

```
 <Columns>  
        <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:HyperLink ID="hpLinkUrl" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("userstoredlink", "{0}") %>' Text="View Details" />
               </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
```

Also remember you need to define `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"` for your gridview.

Or if you don't want to display the `ViewDetails` text when there is no value for `userstoredlink` then changes the `hyperlink` definition as follows

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hpLinkUrl" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("userstoredlink", "{0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("userstoredlink") != "" ? "View Details" :  "" %>' />
```

Comment: that's the `HyperLinkField' field you need to define as part of your gridviews column definition. pls look at my updated answer.

Comment: the id part of the hyperlinkfield throws an error that id is not a valid attribute.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It's an working example. The hyperlink will be active only if there is some value for the `userstoredlink` stored in the database otherwise the text `ViewDetails` will not be active. Let me know if this is what you want.